# Overlay the whole AppBar on the page content in windows phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, appbar

When app bar is present, the height of the app bar affects the content on the rest of the page.
For example, if the app bar has a `Height` of about 25px when `ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal"`, the rest of the content on the page (rootGrid) would have its actual height of Screen Height - 25px. So the app bar is not overlay on page content.

This is visible especially when the content is `VerticalAlignment="Center"` or `Bottom`.

Is there any way to avoid this? Something like a `ZIndex` on the AppBar so that it is displayed over the page content and not trimming it on the bottom side of the screen.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to tell the renderer that the whole "window" should be used when rendering and not just the visible part. By calling `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow)` the renderer will include the areas beneath the chrome of the window (ie the system tray on top of the screen and the app bar at the bottom). The chrome will always be on top of whatever is rendered from xaml.

ApplicationView is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview(v=win.10).aspx).

If you don't want the system tray on the top of the screen to overlap the content, you'll have to compensate with a margin on the root container of your visible xaml.